# Unable to access private method from inside class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**Why can't I access the `check_url` private method in the code below from a class encapsulated method?**

```
class Link < MyModel

  # whitelist fields for security
  attr_accessible :is_valid,
                  :url

  # validations
  validates :is_valid,  :inclusion => { :in => [true, false] }
  validates :url,       :presence => true


  # ===============================================================
  # = class methods (accessible from outside without an instance) =
  # ===============================================================
  class << self

    def is_url_valid(url)
      unless link = Link.find_by_url(url)
        link = Link.create!(:url => url, :is_valid => check_url(url))
      end
      link.is_valid
    end

  end


  # =====================
  # = Private functions =
  # =====================
  private

    # Checks if url is broken
    def check_url(url)
      # do stuff
    end

end
```

**PS. I've also tried using `self.check_url` and it didn't work.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Ruby, private methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver. So you cannot call `self.check_url`. Instead, just call `check_url`.

Your other problem is you defined `check_url` as an instance method, and called it in a class method. Move the `check_url` into the `class << self` scope:

```
class << self
  def is_url_valid(url)
    unless link = Link.find_by_url(url)
      link = Link.create!(:url => url, :is_valid => check_url(url))
    end
    link.is_valid
  end

  private
  # Checks if url is broken
  def check_url(url)
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: Well that's that the code is already -- doesn't work. I've tried both `self.check_url` and `check_url`

Comment: Thanks. That worked -- I didn't know I couldn't access a private function from the base class unless it was contained within the self reference class.

Answer (score 5):

`check_url` is defined as an instance method, and you're trying to access it from a class method (the method is not defined on the class, it's defined on an instance). Change `def check_url` to `def self.check_url` or include it in the `class << self` block.

Are you sure you're getting a private method error, or are you actually getting an undefined method error (both will be a `NoMethodError` but with different messages)?